# Dividing the total number of documents by the number of documents containing the stem

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

`tb_sentence` :

```
================================
|id|doc_id|sentence_id|sentence|
================================
| 1|  1   |   0       |    AB  |
| 2|  1   |   1       |    CD  |
| 3|  2   |   0       |    EF  |
| 4|  2   |   1       |    GH  |
| 5|  2   |   2       |    IJ  |
| 6|  2   |   3       |    KL  |
================================
```

First, I count the number of sentence in every `document_id` and save them in a variable `$total_sentence`.
So the value of `$total_sentence` variable is `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 )`

the second table is `tb_stem` :

```
============================
|id|stem|doc_id|sentence_id|
============================
|1 | B  |  1   |     0     |
|2 | A  |  1   |     1     |
|3 | C  |  2   |     0     |
|4 | A  |  2   |     1     |
|5 | E  |  2   |     2     |
|6 | C  |  2   |     3     |
|7 | D  |  2   |     4     |
|8 | G  |  2   |     5     |
|9 | A  |  2   |     6     |
============================
```

Second, I need to group the datas of `stem` in every `doc_id` and then count the number of `sentence_id` that consist of the result before (`$token`). the concept is dividing the total number of documents by the number of documents containing the stem.
the code :

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(stem) AS unique FROM `tb_stem` group by stem,doc_id ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $token = $row['unique']; //the result $token must be : ABACDEG
}

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT stem, COUNT( DISTINCT sentence_id ) AS ndw FROM `tb_stem` WHERE stem = '$token' GROUP BY stem, doc_id");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
        $ndw = $row['ndw']; //the result must be : 1122111
}

$idf = log($total_sentence / $ndw)+1; //$total_sentence for doc_id = 1 must be divide $ndw with the doc_id = 2, etc
```

But The result is not separate between the different document like the table below :

```
============================
|id|word|doc_id|  ndw |idf |
============================
|1 | A  |      |      |    |
|2 | B  |      |      |    |
|3 | C  |      |      |    |
|4 | D  |      |      |    |
|5 | E  |      |      |    |
|6 | G  |      |      |    |
============================
```

the result must be :

```
 ============================
|id|word|doc_id|  ndw |idf |
============================
|1 | A  |   1  |      |    |
|2 | B  |   1  |      |    |
|3 | A  |   2  |      |    |
|4 | C  |   2  |      |    |
|5 | D  |   2  |      |    |
|6 | E  |   2  |      |    |
|7 | G  |   2  |      |    |
============================
```

Help me please, Thank you :)

The formula of idf is `idf = log(N/df)` where `N` is the number of document and `df` is the number of documents in which a term (t) appears. Every sentence is considered as a document.
Here is example for idf calculation :
Document : `Do you read poetry while flying. Many people find it relaxing to read on long flights`

```
=================================================
|     Term     | Document1(D1)| D2| df |   idf  |
=================================================
|     find     |     0        | 1 |  1 |log(2/1)|
|     fly      |     1        | 1 |  2 |log(2/2)|
|     long     |     0        | 1 |  1 |log(2/1)|
|    people    |     0        | 1 |  1 |log(2/1)|
|    poetry    |     1        | 0 |  1 |log(2/1)|
|     read     |     1        | 1 |  2 |log(2/2)|
|    relax     |     0        | 1 |  1 |log(2/1)|
=================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will give you the table you're looking for:

```
SELECT t1.doc_id, t2.token as word, t2.token_freq as df, 
log(t1.docs/t2.token_freq) as idf
FROM 
(SELECT doc_id,count(sentence_id) as docs from tb_sentence group by doc_id) as t1,
(SELECT DISTINCT(stem) as token, doc_id, COUNT(sentence_id) as token_freq 
      FROM tb_stem GROUP BY doc_id, token) as t2
WHERE t1.doc_id = t2.doc_id
```

*Note: Unique in your original query is a reserved word in MySQL and will give you errors.*

Comment: thank you so much james ! :) I've tried your query, and added some correction in this line -> `LOG( (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(sentence_id)) FROM tb_sentence) / COUNT(sentence_id)) + 1  as idf `. When I run the code in only one document, it works well (give correct result, example idf = 3.944) but when I run it in more than one document, the result is changed. it seems that another document gives affect to another. for example, the result idf = 3.944 is changed become idf =  6.3890. it seems that the process still doesn't run in every different document but in whole document at once

Comment: I may have misunderstood the formula for idf which I thought was log(#of documents / occurrence). It's been a while since I've done any work with that formula. Should it be log (#of words in document 1/#of occurences of word x in document 1)?

Comment: in my thought, it should be the first formula. but the documents (in the formula) are represented by sentences in that document. I've added the formula in my question above. in my case, I have many different documents, and I need to count idf in every document. the problem is the code still doesn't calculate in each document, but in whole documents at once

Comment: I've updated the query with what I believe reflects your desired calculation.